# Select dropdown key for ipython widget

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, widget, ipython

In creating an ipython dropdown widget,

```
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import display

d = {"1": "a", "2": "b"}

dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=d)
display(dropdown)
```

I can use

```
print dropdown.value
```

to print the value of the selected key from the dropdown widget.  How can I obtain the key ("1", "2") that is clicked in the dropdown?  Using

```
print dropdown.key
```

does not work.

Comment: One option I could do is pass 'd.keys()' to options, but I want to know if there is a method to obtain the key from just passing in the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 1):

The *key* is stored in `dropdown.selected_label`

I couldnt' find any other reference that [this one](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_selection.py#L34).